# Android Notification - java.lang.Throwable: stack dump

Tags: android, notifications, stack, dump

I am trying to start a notification when I receive a new message. It works - the notication is created, showed on the status bar and when I click on it, it opens my Intent successfully, but in the LogCat I'm receiving

> java.lang.Throwable: stack dump

This is the log from the LogCat:

```
01-26 17:22:53.661: W/System.err(11868): java.lang.Throwable: stack dump
01-26 17:22:53.669: W/System.err(11868):    at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:496)
01-26 17:22:53.669: W/System.err(11868):    at android.app.Notification$Builder.applyStandardTemplate(Notification.java:1504)
01-26 17:22:53.669: W/System.err(11868):    at android.app.Notification$Builder.makeContentView(Notification.java:1624)
01-26 17:22:53.669: W/System.err(11868):    at android.app.Notification$Builder.buildUnstyled(Notification.java:1673)
01-26 17:22:53.669: W/System.err(11868):    at android.app.Notification$Builder.build(Notification.java:1726)
01-26 17:22:53.669: W/System.err(11868):    at android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean.build(NotificationCompatJellybean.java:98)
01-26 17:22:53.669: W/System.err(11868):    at android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$NotificationCompatImplJellybean.build(NotificationCompat.java:142)
01-26 17:22:53.669: W/System.err(11868):    at android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Builder.build(NotificationCompat.java:558)
01-26 17:22:53.669: W/System.err(11868):    at myPackage.ChatActivity.createNotification(ChatActivity.java:335)
01-26 17:22:53.669: W/System.err(11868):    at myPackage.ChatActivity$2.processMessage(ChatActivity.java:207)
01-26 17:22:53.677: W/System.err(11868):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.Chat.deliver(Chat.java:169)
01-26 17:22:53.677: W/System.err(11868):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.ChatManager.deliverMessage(ChatManager.java:248)
01-26 17:22:53.677: W/System.err(11868):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.ChatManager.access$200(ChatManager.java:49)
01-26 17:22:53.677: W/System.err(11868):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.ChatManager$2.processPacket(ChatManager.java:131)
01-26 17:22:53.677: W/System.err(11868):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection$ListenerWrapper.notifyListener(Connection.java:867)
01-26 17:22:53.677: W/System.err(11868):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.PacketReader$ListenerNotification.run(PacketReader.java:455)
01-26 17:22:53.677: W/System.err(11868):    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:442)
01-26 17:22:53.685: W/System.err(11868):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-26 17:22:53.685: W/System.err(11868):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-26 17:22:53.685: W/System.err(11868):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-26 17:22:53.685: W/System.err(11868):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-26 17:22:53.685: W/System.err(11868):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

This is my code to create the notification:

```
int id = 0;
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("userId", msg.getFrom());
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
stackBuilder.addParentStack(ChatActivity.class);
stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

PendingIntent pInt = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

NotificationCompat.Builder notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
  .setContentTitle(msg.getFrom())
  .setContentText(msg.getBody())
  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_done)
  .setAutoCancel(true);


notification.setContentIntent(pInt);
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(id, notification.build());
```

Can somebody tell me, what's the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Same here with the regular (non-compat) NotificationBuilder, even when reduced to only setting a title. Happens here on a Samsung S2 with Android 4.1.2. Also the notification seems to work fine, regardless of the log output (which is also on WARNING level, not ERROR).